# Is there a function where the spread operator changes the value?

Tags: javascript

```js
let abc = [
  { name: "a" },
  { name: "b"}
];

const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
  arr.map(item => {
    if (item.name === oldName) {
      return {
        ...item,
        name
      }
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });

let updateName = editName("a", "c", abc)
console.log(updateName[0])
```

I am currently learning to change the value through "map".
However, I don't know why the value is replaced by the spread operations in the "if" section

dose spread operator have that function?

`...item` is `name: "a"`, isn't it?

Comment: _"However, I don't know why the value is replaced by the spread operations in the "if" section"_ - That's the whole reason of that `if...else...` o.O

Comment: `arr.map((o) => ({ ...o, name: o.name === oldName ? name : o.name }));`

Comment: _"`...item` is `name: "a"`, isn't it?"_ Yes (kinda), hence the returned object "looks" like `{ name: "a", name: "c" }`. But you cannot have two properties with the same name...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spread operator merges the properties of the objects.

Suppose there are two objects:

```
let obj1 = {
    name: 'a'
}

let obj2 = {
    name: 'b'
}
```

Now lets merge their properties using the spread operator,

```
let finalObj = {}

finalObj = {
    ...obj1,
    ...obj2
}

console.log(finalObj)
// Output: { name: 'b' }

finalObj = {
    ...obj2,
    ...obj1
}

console.log(finalObj)
// Output: { name: 'a' }
```

If the properties are same, the value gets overridden.

In your case, if you want the spread operator to override the property values in the object, then add it below the key that is to be overridden.

```
let abc = [
    { name: "a" },
    { name: "b"}
  ];
  
  const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
    arr.map(item => {
      if (item.name === oldName) {
        return {
          
          name,
          ...item,
        }
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
  
  let updateName = editName("a", "c", abc)
  console.log(updateName[0])
```

Comment: Aha! If the properties are the same, it's overwritten....
I only knew the ability to tie the arrangement.
Thank you.

Comment: _"Spread operator merges the properties..."_ - This has nothing to do with the spread _syntax_. An object cannot have two properties with the same name. If that's the case then they are overwritten in the order they appear in the object.

Answer (score 2):

Spread there helps by:

- Concisely creating a new object with all the properties of `item`, plus a `name` property
- Not mutating the original `item`

If you didn't use spread (or an equivalent), and instead used something like `item.name = name;`, the objects in the original array would be mutated, which is likely not desirable:

```js
// original code
let abc = [
  { name: "a" },
  { name: "b"}
];

const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
  arr.map(item => {
    if (item.name === oldName) {
      return {
        ...item,
        name
      }
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });

let updateName = editName("a", "c", abc)
console.log(updateName[0])
console.log(abc[0]);
```

```js
// bad, mutation code without spread syntax
let abc = [
  { name: "a" },
  { name: "b"}
];

const editName = (oldName, name, arr) =>
  arr.map(item => {
    if (item.name === oldName) {
      item.name = name;
    }
    return item;
  });

let updateName = editName("a", "c", abc)
console.log(updateName[0])
console.log(abc[0]);
```

Above, the bad code mutates the object, as you can see by `abc[0]` logging the mutated name, rather than the original name that was in `abc[0]`.

If you meant why it wasn't

```
  return {
    item,
    name
  }
```

it's because that would result in an object like

```
{
  item: {
    name: 'a',
  },
  name: 'c'
}
```

with an `item` property (which probably isn't desired). Using `...` combines the contents of the spread object with the rest of the object literal.

Comment: Where's the answer for: _"However, I don't know why the value is replaced by the spread operations in the "if" section"_ ?

Comment: Because if a new object (created via spreading) wasn't returned, it'd mutate the object in the original array, which likely wouldn't be desirable. (unless `Object.assign` or a method that avoids mutation was used instead)

Comment: I didn't think about why spread operator is used. Thanks to you, I understand more deeply. 
Thank you.